# Is it a correct usage?

Tags: sentence-usage

"If you ask my favourite activity, I would say it is eating."  Is it correct or I should use "will" instead of would or another thing

Comment: *If you ask **me** my favourite activity, I would say it is eating.* Without the **me**, it's your favourite activity that's being addressed, not you.

Comment: What research have you done on this issue? (There are many questions on this site, for example, that ask about the proper usage of "will" and "would"; it even has [a tag](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/will-would) to make it easy to find such questions.)

Answer (score 1):

For "will", you would use this:

> If you ask **me** my favourite activity, I **will** say [it is] eating.

For "would", you would use the past tense:

> If you ask**ed** me my favourite activity, I **would** say [it is] eating.

Further to this, you'd be much more likely hear this without the "it is", which I've enclosed in brackets for that reason.

Comment: I think the version with "asked" is more natural here, for discussing a general condition, rather than something that's very specific to the current time. (In contrast, "If you keep poking me, I'll drop the drinks" means now or in the near future.)